# JavaFX, Tableview, Как поставить PropertyValueFactory на колонку из листа?

Tags: javafx, tableview

У меня есть TableView c несколькими столбцами. TableView заполняю объектами У объекта 2 поля: строка и список

```
String сar = "Mazda"

List carParts;
```

В списке несколько других строк, например "wheels", "engine", "suspension"

Первый столбец `Car.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("car"));` отображает марку.

Как задать, чтобы второй третий и следующие столбцы брали поле из первого списка? Например, как–то так: второй столбец `Wheels.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(carParts.get(0));`

Answer (score 1):

К примеру реализуйте свою фабрику:

```
    carColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Car, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
         public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Car, String> p) {
             return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(((Car)p.getValue()).getParts.get(0));
         }
      });
```

Обратите внимание что данная фабрика предоставляет доступные только для чтения объекты.Если вам необходимо отслеживать состояние ячейки на предмет изменения пользователем рекомендую использовать Property в самом объекте.